# Calculate closed loop gain with Oscilloscope measurements

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, closed-loop

Using these reading from Agilent MSO-X2012a oscilloscope:

[image]

from this circuit:

[image]

How do you calculate the close loop gain using these measurements. I already calculated by hand and got Av = 11V.

Comment: Av does not have units of volts; it's unitless (or you can write it as V/V if you like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using these reading from Agilent MSO-X2012a oscilloscope:

and

> How do you calculate the close loop gain using these measurements.

You can look in detail at the picture: -

[image]

And see that channel 1 is about 11 times bigger than channel 2 i.e. gain is 1 + 10k/1k.

Comment: But I got the same readings on a buffer op amp with no resistors. And gain calculated was 1.

Comment: You need to carefully check your oscilloscope settings.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options. I'd recommend that you do a math channel and divide your output by your input. You can then turn on a measurement to measure the average of the math channel waveform. You could also do measurements on the waveforms themselves and do the division by hand/in your head.